# How to dynamically create block of content and then add class?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm pretty bad at Angularjs, sorry. I need to create 'commentary box' onclick, then i need to insert this "box" to global-wrap-container (it's a class name).

Here i have my "comment box"

```
  <div class="comment-reply-wrap" >
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="info" >
        <div class="left-side-info">
          <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="avatar" class="avatar">
          <span class="name">{{repUsers.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side-info">
          <p class="user-text" ng-bind-html='repUsers.text'>
            <img class="comment-image" src="">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <span class="comment-email">{{repUsers.email}}</span>
          <span class="comment-date">10/29/2010 at 6:40AM</span>
          <button type="submit" class="reply" ng-click="createReplyForm($event)">
            <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the function, where i push information and "commentary" appears.

```
$scope.addRepUser = function() {
$scope.bool = false;

//Dynamically create array of objects and push data
  $scope.repUsers.push({
  name: $scope.repUser.name,
  email: $scope.repUser.email,
  text: $scope.repUser.text
  });


//Clear input fields in main form
$scope.repUser.name = '';
$scope.repUser.email = '';
$scope.repUser.text = ''; };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ng-repeat

```
<div class="your-class" ng-repat="user in repUsers">
 <span class="comment-email">{{user.email}}</span>
 <span class="comment-date">10/29/2010 at 6:40AM</span>
 <span class="comment">{{user.text}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried ng-repeat. But i still can't reach the needed result. Also, how then insert this 'comment boxes' to another div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop thinking 'insert div' like, this is not jquery.
In angular, you can put a div in your html that will be showed depending on a boolean value of your scope.

```
<div ng-show="shouldBeDisplayed"></div>
```

And in the controller:

```
function displayDiv(){
    $scope.shouldBeDisplayed = true;
    //use the line below if you want to toggle show
    //$scope.shouldBeDisplayed = !$scope.shouldBeDisplayed;
}
```

To display the list of comments, you need to use an array:

```
$scope.comments = [];
```

On submit you have to push your object inside this array. It will be displayed with an `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="your-class" ng-repat="comment in comments">
</div>
```

The mechanic here should be:

- click answer comment
- controller should update the boolean value on click
- it will display your form (and hide the list if you want to)
- submit form
- push the values into the desired list and update the boolean to hide the form

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4t37u642/

Comment: Thanks, but maybe i wrote my question incomprehensibly. After creating comment using ng-repeat it appears, yes, but how then i could insert replied comment inside the div of comment that i've replied?

Comment: See the fiddle I added

Comment: okey, but i still don't know, how to append this comment after creating, to any div. Maybe i should do this in the function, where i push info in object or how? Please, help.

Comment: you mean like that ? : http://jsfiddle.net/4t37u642/3/  To continue like that, you will need to do some recursion, which is quite a pain in angular

Comment: oh, i see. You mean if i want to make 5-level of more cascade comments it will be a harcode?

Comment: Not necessary, if you are using angular 1.5 you can create a recursive component quite easily.